# "Unfortunately, ROC has stopped." When code to retrive data from firebase(Login). NoActionBar Solution also not working

Tags: android, firebase, authentication, crash

When I jump from MainActivity to AdminLog it works when adminLog.java contains the code as shown below. I have also searched for solution Like enabling noAction bar but it also doen't work. Not only for login code but it is shows same issue when I try to retrieve data from my firebase database.

```
package com.example.roc;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class adminLog extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button btnSignin;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button mgo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_log);
        mgo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.adminLoginBtn);
        mgo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(adminLog.this,adminWorking.class));
            }
        });
}
}
```

But it stops Working when I add login code in adminLog.java file which is also shown below.

```
package com.example.roc;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class adminLog extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txtEmail, txtPassword;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button btnSignin;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Button mgo;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_admin_log);


        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        initializeUI();

        btnSignin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                loginUserAccount();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loginUserAccount() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        String email, password;
        email = txtEmail.getText().toString();
        password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter email...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(adminLog.this, adminWorking.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login failed! Please try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void initializeUI() {
        txtEmail= findViewById(R.id.adminETxt);
        txtPassword = findViewById(R.id.adminPTxt);

        btnSignin = findViewById(R.id.adminLoginBtn);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }

    }
```

adminlog.xml file code is also given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".adminLog">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/adminLoginBtn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:text="Login"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adminPTxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/customerLoginBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:hint="Enter your password"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/adminLoginBtn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/adminETxt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="332dp"
        android:hint="Entere Your E-Mail"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="119dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="139dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="139dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="139dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="139dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="448dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

What should I do to get rid of this problem.